# Tensorflow-GPU without NVIDIA，possible？

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

I don't have a NVIDIA graphics card, but I need to use tensorflow-gpu. Is this feasible? what should I do?

Comment: No, it is not possible to use the GPU capability of Tensorflow without GPU.

Comment: Would it not be more sensible to tell us what you _do_ have? AFAIK AMD is getting some love, though it's experimental (or my data is obsolete).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google's colab for free directly in your browser:

> https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#recent=true
>   https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb

You can create easily a notebook to run tensorflow (wich is already installed) from the file menu.

To activate the GPU simply select "GPU" in the Accelerator drop-down in Notebook Settings (either through the Edit menu or the command palette at cmd/ctrl-shift-P).

Comment: Thank you so much! But the memory of notebook is not enough to run my code....Thank you for inspiring me!